# Force old revision to be the newest revision - SVN

Tags: svn

I have an old revision which works fantastic and I'd like to reverse the past few revisions I've made in SVN. How can I simply remove those revisions and make the HEAD be a specific revision. That way, when I press update, it goes to that revision, and not the real current reivision?

Comment: And what about everyone else who has already checked out those later revisions? You must **commit** the code of the old revision as the newest revision.

Comment: why do people on here not ever just answer the question. I wouldn't ask the question if I wasn't okay with replacing the code. and secondly, that would be a fantastic plan except it won't let you commit without performing an update.

Comment: In addition to complaining about a **comment** and not an **answer**, you have missed my point. You can't expect SVN to allow an operation that has the potential to totally mess up everyone else's state. As you can see in your accepted answer, a new commit is indeed involved.

Comment: @LarsH When I answer, I do it in an answer. This was a **comment**.

Comment: @LarsH A question is definitely not an answer and the second sentence is definitely a comment: it mentions an important constraint on a solution without providing one. Maybe someone else would consider that good enough for an answer; not me. In my second comment I only elaborate my initial point in response to OP's criticism of my supposed "answer".

Comment: @Marko: Have you never encountered a question that was an answer?

Comment: @LarsH I certainly have; it's called a *rhetorical question* and my question is not an example of one.

Comment: @Marko, you have refuted your statement that "A question is definitely not an answer." But we're getting off topic. I was hoping to help you see what CodeGuy meant, or v.v., but I don't think any progress is being made.

Comment: @LarsH **My** question was definitely not an answer, but thank you for carefully driving me into making slightly imprecise statements wherein you can then point out trifling contradictions. This is all very much fun.

Comment: @Marko, my purpose wasn't to trap you. It was to help clear away incorrect claims and reasoning so as to help us get back to reality. BTW I clicked on "automatically move comments to chat" but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `svn` book:

> **Undoing Changes**
>
> Another common use for `svn merge` is to roll back a change that has already been committed. Suppose you're working away happily on a working copy of `/calc/trunk`, and you discover that the change made way back in revision 303, which changed `integer.c`, is completely wrong. It never should have been committed. You can use `svn merge` to “undo” the change in your working copy, and then commit the local modification to the repository. All you need to do is to specify a reverse difference:

```
$ svn merge -r 303:302 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
U  integer.c

$ svn status
M  integer.c

$ svn diff
…
# verify that the change is removed
…

$ svn commit -m "Undoing change committed in r303."
Sending        integer.c
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 350.
```

For more details, see the rest of the ["Undoing Changes" section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you do an SVN HELP MERGE, look at the 3rd form shown (-r N:M). I believe this is the method you want to use.