# Deleting the last few revisions: SVN best practice

Tags: svn, undo, revision

A fellow student and I are working on a project and we are both new to Subversion. We realized that the last few revisions of our project have some flaws. So we decided to do away with those revisions and start again from the point where those problems were introduced.

What's the most appropriate way to do this in SVN? Should we create a new 'branch' from an old version of the project and then continue working on that branch?

or should I use something like this? (Using merge to undo changes)

[Force old revision to be the newest revision - SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885640/force-old-revision-to-be-the-newest-revision-svn)

EDIT: For benefit of anybody else with the same question.. 
The link given describes the most suitable procedure. If you're using tortoise SVN, search for "roll back tortoise SVN" and you should find a page in the Tortoise SVN manual.

Comment: The accepted answer on the post that you linked is the correct way to resolve the issue. Those instructions come directly from the Subversion manual - do you have a specific reason to question its validity?

Comment: no.. I just didn't know whether it was the best way to process in my situation. 
Anyhow, that is the method that I ended up following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exactly which all are the wrong checkin, then continue with 2nd(merge to undo changes) option.
If that is difficult, then continue with creating new branch.
Note: **Creating new brach/tag in the exising repository doesn't overload the server with additional hardcopy,but it managing using repo version number mapping**. Anyway client doesnt want to bother about that..But you need to configure svn server for user privilages, backup plan and sheduling, and need to inform to the svn clients regarding new path and all. Make it simple as possible according to your setup environment.

Comment: This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @aloc can you specific, what wrong with this answer. I had a thought of compainge both ways( taking new brach/rollback false checkin ).

Comment: I shared my observation on SVN server ( csvn\data ) size, when creating new brach/tag. I checked the space before and after creating new brach. It seems, there is no additional copy in server side. But It manage by self. I mean to convey, server is not overloaded with hardcopy of the brach tree. Hope this make sense.

Comment: I don't see how that answers the question when the previous question the OP found has precisely what he needs in the previous question linked.

Comment: OP need best answer out of "rollbak" and "creating new branch" ? Recently i got experienced same issue, that is why I shared my knowledge on this on answer.